# Is there a way to pass data from a python list into particular fields of an sqlite database using a django command?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have data that has been scraped from a website, parsed, and cleaned into the pieces I need. The data is stored in a two dimensional list as such `[[address1, name1, ip1], [address2, name2, ip2]]`. The scraping and storing of the aforementioned data is done through a django command, and I would like to update my model with the same command as it validates the data. I also have a model with the following fields and attributes:

```
class MonitoredData(models.Model):
   external_id = models.UUIDField(
       primary_key = True,
       default = uuid.uuid4,
       editable = False)
   mac_address = models.CharField(max_length=12)
   ipv4_address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   interface_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
   update_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

`address1` needs to go in the `mac_address` field, `name1` needs to go into the `interface_name` field, and `ip1` needs to go into `ipv4_address` field. The other fields need to auto-fill according to their attributes.

The django command that grabs and parses the data is:

```
class Command(BaseCommand):
def handle(self, *args, **options):
    url1 = 'https://next.json-generator.com/api/json/get/41wV8bj_O'
    url2 = 'https://next.json-generator.com/api/json/get/Nk48cbjdO'

    res1 = requests.get(url1)
    data1 = str(res1.content)

    res2 = requests.get(url2)
    data2 = str(res2.content)

    parsedData1 = parse1(data1)

    goodMac1 = []
    badMac1 = []

    for k in parsedData1:
        if len(k[0]) == 12:
            if match(k[0]):
                goodMac1.append(k)
        else:
            badMac1.append(k)


    parsedData2 = parse2(data2)

    goodMac2 = []
    badMac2 = []

    for j in parsedData2:
        if len(j[0]) == 12:
            if match(j[0]):
                goodMac2.append(j)
        else:
            badMac2.append(j)
```

I'd like to store the data into the database instead of appending to the goodMac list in the nested if statement.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated, I am using Python 3.7.5 and Django 3.0.5

Comment: What exactly do you mean here by a `using a django command?`

Comment: So I'm using a django command to run the code that gets the data in the first place, here, I can't include all of it but here:class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, *args, **options):


        form = MonitoredInterfaceForm()

        for k in parsedData1:
            if len(k[0]) == 12:
                if match(k[0]):
                    goodMac1.append(k)
            else:
                badMac1.append(k)

Comment: I'd like to, instead of appending to the goodMac1 list, just insert the data into the appropriate fields there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out! I hope this will save someone all the time and trouble I went through solving this, the solution, as I suspected, was fairly trivial once I found it. You import your model, instantiate an object of it, then update the fields and use the save() function. Here is the fixed code.

```
import requests

from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError

from Monitor.models import *
from Monitor.parse1 import parse1
from Monitor.parse2 import parse2
from Monitor.matcher import match

class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        url1 = 'https://next.json-generator.com/api/json/get/41wV8bj_O'
        url2 = 'https://next.json-generator.com/api/json/get/Nk48cbjdO'
    res1 = requests.get(url1)
    data1 = str(res1.content)

    res2 = requests.get(url2)
    data2 = str(res2.content)

    parsedData1 = parse1(data1)

    goodMac1 = []
    badMac1 = []


    for k in parsedData1:
        if len(k[0]) == 12:
            if match(k[0]):
                monInter = MonitoredData()
                monInter.mac_address = k[0]
                monInter.interface_name = k[1]
                monInter.ipv4_address = k[2]
                monInter.save()
                goodMac1.append(k)

        else:
            badMac1.append(k)


    parsedData2 = parse2(data2)

    goodMac2 = []
    badMac2 = []

    for j in parsedData2:
        if len(j[0]) == 12:
            if match(j[0]):
                goodMac2.append(j)
        else:
            badMac2.append(j)
```

Here are links to the documentation I ultimately ended up using:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.save
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/